# send seprate request on each request of axios

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have a question
I want to send seprate request for each request send by axios , I want to get my notification in `api/getNotification`  and send this request seprate when each axios request send like:

`api/getNews`
when this request sending after that the request 
`api/getNotification`
send too

I don't want to use `axios.all`

is there any way to define in like interceptor/global ?

Comment: I want to help you, but i have a question, why you dont want to use axios.all? Is there a specific need?

Comment: i'm new in vuejs , I use axios in all component if I use like this I need to add in all component I know It's better to use axios like service and use from then but It's my first project and I need to solve like this

Comment: To clarify, you want to first send api/getNews and once that response comes back then send the api/getNotification?

Comment: yes, thats right

Comment: since the axios returns a promise you should call the api/getNotification after the api/getNews is resolved (i.e) in then portion of api/getNews

Comment: Isnt that the same as axios all? Promise chaining

Comment: I know that but I need to write globaly line inceptors of axios ,

Comment: An interceptor will never work on this because it's non-transactional. You have no idea about requests before or after unless you push them all into an array, re-order them, and then resolve them manually, which is more expensive and confusing than just using promise chaining.